# Sending scanner inputs to a unit test

Tags: java, junit

i have a class with few variables. these variables get input from user. i am trying to write a test case so, i have initialized the class object. the problem is how can i send the input to those variable which require user inputs.

This is my class

```
  package src;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    int initialBookPrice;

    int discountPrice;

    int basePrice ;

    int budget ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main Obj = new Main();

            Obj.initialBookPrice = Obj.inputReader("Initial Book Price");

            Obj.discountPrice = Obj.inputReader("Discount Price");

            Obj.basePrice= Obj.inputReader("Base Price");

            Obj.budget= Obj.inputReader("Budget");

            if (Obj.budget < Obj.initialBookPrice) {
                System.out.printf("0 Books, $%s remaining", Obj.budget);
            } else if (Obj.budget == Obj.initialBookPrice) {
                System.out.printf("1 Book, $0 remaining");
            } else {
                System.out.println(Obj.offerFunction());
            }



    }

    public  int inputReader(String variableName) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter the %s: ",variableName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = true;
        int n = 0;
        while (flag) {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
            if (n >= 0) {
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.printf("Please enter a valid Positive %s",variableName);
                System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the %s: ",variableName);
            }

        }
        return n;


    }

    public String offerFunction() {
        int diffPrice = this.initialBookPrice - this.basePrice;
        int numberOfBooks = 0;
        int tempBudget = this.budget;
        int remaining = 0;
        for (int i = this.initialBookPrice; i >= diffPrice; i= i - this.discountPrice) {
            numberOfBooks+=1;
            tempBudget -= i;
        }
        numberOfBooks += tempBudget/this.basePrice;
        remaining = tempBudget % this.basePrice;
        return String.format(" %s books, $%s remaining", numberOfBooks,remaining);

    }
    }
```

This is my test class

```
package src;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.junit.Test;
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void testInputReader() {
        Main Obj = new Main();
        String input = "50";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        input = "40";
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        input = "25";
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);

        input = "300";
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);

        assertEquals("8 books, $9 remaining", Obj.offerFunction());

    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are already using System.setIn(in); to feed input. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Don't let variable names begin in uppercase, it gets confused with class names, which actually start in uppercase. The name `Obj` looks like a class like `String` or `InputStream`, but is actually a variable.

Comment: @Sachin Aggarwal, when i run the code, it is just running without  saying pass or failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert:

```
    Main Obj = new Main();
    String input = "50 40 25 300";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    assertEquals(50, Obj.inputReader("anyVariable"));
```

in your test, you will see that replacing System.in with your own stream worked just fine.

If you want to test the whole functionality of the main program, you should probably make that an own method, maybe printPrices():

```
public void printPrice() {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    initialBookPrice = inputReader("Initial Book Price");

    discountPrice = inputReader("Discount Price");

    basePrice= inputReader("Base Price");

    budget= inputReader("Budget");

    if (budget < initialBookPrice) {
        System.out.printf("0 Books, $%s remaining", budget);
    } else if (budget == initialBookPrice) {
        System.out.printf("1 Book, $0 remaining");
    } else {
        System.out.println(offerFunction());
    }

}
```

Note that Scanner is promoted to a field in the class. If now you insert

```
String input = "50 40 25 300";
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
System.setIn(in);
Obj.printPrice();
```

in your test method, it will work just fine.

However, from a testability perspective, it would be even better to have that method return a String, because then you can actually assert something. But that's a different matter...

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't want to unit test internal classes (like System or Scanner), they're tested by JVM itself and we assume they work properly.

In your method inputReader you wait for user input. To simulate that behavior in a unit test, you create a so called "mock". It makes your test think, that something happened but it didn't happen at all (e.g. user input). Very simplified explanation but you get the idea.

To create a mock you might want to use a library like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)